# Python: How to merge two dictionaries recursivly with equal subdictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have two dictionaries in python with this structure (subdictionaries) and I want to merge them. I want to integrate the key and values from ['page']['results'] together into one, with preserving the structure.

DictA:

```
{
   "**page**":{
      "**results**":[
         {
            "*id*":"164895045",
            "type":"page",
            "status":"current",
            "title":"Testeintrag",
            "extensions":{
               "position":"none"
            },
            "_links":{
               "webui":"/display/Orga/Testeintrag",
               "edit":"/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=164895045",
            },
            "_expandable":{
               "container":"/rest/api/space/OrgaIB15",
               "metadata":"",
            }
         }, ...
```

DictB:

```
{
   "**page**":{
      "**results**":[
         {
            "*id*":"169020312",
            "type":"page",
            "status":"current",
            "title":"IDERA Tools",
            "extensions":{
               "position":"none"
            },
            "_links":{
               "webui":"/display/Orga/IDERA+Tools",
               "edit":"/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=169020312",
            },
            "_expandable":{
               "container":"/rest/api/space/Orga",
               "metadata":"",
            }
         }, ...
```

Wanted Result:

```
{
   "**page**":{
      "**results**":[
         {
            "*id*":"164895045",
            "type":"page",
            "status":"current",
            "title":"Testeintrag",
            "extensions":{
               "position":"none"
            },
            "_links":{
               "webui":"/display/Orga/Testeintrag",
               "edit":"/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=164895045",
            },
            "_expandable":{
               "container":"/rest/api/space/OrgaIB15",
               "metadata":"",
            }
         },
         {
            "*id*":"169020312",
            "type":"page",
            "status":"current",
            "title":"IDERA Tools",
            "extensions":{
               "position":"none"
            },
            "_links":{
               "webui":"/display/Orga/IDERA+Tools",
               "edit":"/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=169020312",
            },
            "_expandable":{
               "container":"/rest/api/space/Orga",
               "metadata":"",
            }
         }, ...
```

I have tried several solutions but the keys and values in ['page']['results'] will allways be overwritten by the next/last dictionary that was migrated.

Comment: If you post one of your attempts to solve this problem & explain the issue(s) you have with it, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: In the example you only show the two dictionaries appended, which I believe is not necessarily what you want. Can you please show a more complex example to better explain what you are looking for?

Comment: Take a look at the built-in *extend()* functionality of a Python list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
merged_results = dict_1['**page**']['**results**'] + dict_2['**page**']['**results**']
merged_dict = {
    "**page**": {
        "**results**": merged_results
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello mighty_mike.  
This did the job for me.  

`merged_results = dictA['page']['results'] + dictB['page']['results']
merged_dict = {
    "page": {
        "results": merged_results
    }
}`